# Setting cookies in Feign client

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a rest endpoint (Application A) which is getting called from UI and ServletRequest from UI has all the cookies. From application A, I am calling Application B through FeignClient. How can I pass all the cookies to application B using Feign?